# Trigonometry functions from series expansion

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am trying to write functions which emulate `math.sin` and `math.tan` but, instead of using the `math` library, performing the calculation using a series expansion.

The formulae are from Mathematics SE, [How would you calculate the Tangent without a calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455870/how-would-you-calculate-the-tangent-without-a-calculator):

> sin(x) = x − x^3/3! + x^5/5! −...
>
> tan(x) = sin(x) / √(1 − sin(x)^2)

This is my attempt, but I could not figure out how to perform the sign flipping `+` / `-` / `+` / ... part of the series expansion for `sin`:

```
from math import factorial

res = 0
for i in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]:
    res += 1**i/factorial(i)

print(res)  # 1.1752011936438016
```

The result is not correct because I have not applied a `+` / `-` switch. I could add an `if` / `else` clause but this seems messy. Is  there a better way?

*Note*: This question is an embellished version of a [now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223025/how-to-write-my-own-implementation-of-tanx-in-python-where-x-is-the-radians) that was posted yesterday by @Lana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid recalculating x**n and the factorial at each step by calculating the next term of the sum using the previous one:

```
def sin2(x, n=20):
    curr =  x
    res = curr 
    for i in range(2, n, 2):
        curr *= - x**2/(i*(i+1))
        res += curr
    return res
```

Compared to jpp's version, it's about twice as fast:

```
from math import factorial

def sin(x, n=20):
    return sum(x**j/factorial(j)*(1 if i%2==0 else -1)
               for i, j in enumerate(range(1, n, 2)))


%timeit sin(0.7)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.52 µs per loop
%timeit sin2(0.7)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.54 µs per loop
```

And it can get a bit faster if we calculate `- x**2` once and for all:

```
def sin3(x, n=20):
    curr =  x
    res = 0
    minus_x_squared = - x**2
    for i in range(2, n, 2):
        res += curr
        curr *= minus_x_squared/(i*(i+1))
    return res

%timeit sin2(0.7)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.6 µs per loop

%timeit sin3(0.7)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.54 µs per loop
```

Comment: That is definitely much better! +1

Comment: Ah, I was editing the same thing in mine :). But yes, definitely deserves +1.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Below is one way using `sum` with `enumerate` for your series expansion.

`enumerate` works by taking each value of an iterable and attaching an index, i.e. 0 for the first item, 1 for the second item, etc. Then we only need to test whether the index is even or odd and use a [ternary statement](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator).

In addition, you can use `range` instead of listing the odd numbers required in your expansion.

```
from math import factorial

def sin(x, n=20):
    return sum(x**j/factorial(j)*(1 if i%2==0 else -1)
               for i, j in enumerate(range(1, n, 2)))

def tan(x):
    return sin(x) / (1-(sin(x))**2)**0.5

print(tan(1.2))  # 2.572151622126318
```

You can avoid the need for a ternary statement and `enumerate` altogether:

```
def sin(x, n=20):
    return sum((-1)**i * x**(2*i+1) / factorial(2*i+1) for i in range(n))
```

If you write out the first few terms by hand, the equivalence will become clear.

**Notes:**

- The sign of the `tan` function is only correct for 1st and 4th quadrants. This is consistent with the formulae you have provided. You can perform a trivial transformation to the input to account for this.
- You can improve accuracy by increasing parameter `n`.
- You can also calculate factorial without a library, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: or you can just use `-1**(i%2)` instead of ternary. Because *-1^0 -> 1* and *-1^1 -> -1*

Comment: @Ev.Kounis wouldn't that make the output "technically" complex?

Comment: Can also group adjacent pairs of terms with opposite sign to avoid the if-statement, e.g. `x - x^3/3!`, `x^5/5! - x^7/7!` ... `x^(2i - 1) / (2i - 1)! * (1 - x^2 / (2i * (2i + 1)))`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Why would it? It is not `sqrt(-1)` we are doing, we are raising -1 to an integer power. The grouping idea is really nice too!

Comment: @meowgoesthedog `type(-1**0)` returns `<class 'int'>`. So does `type(-1**1)`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Sorry for being pendantic, but `-1**0` is not a special case. In fact, neither is `-1**0.5`; **`(-1)**0.5`** is.